# Prove that $\frac{d}{dx}\left(3x^2+4\sqrt{x}\right) = 6x+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Prove that $\frac{d}{dx}\left(3x^2+4\sqrt{x}\right) = 6x+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$

Note 2 things here please: **I KNOW** the differentiation rules, **I KNOW**  that $\frac{d}{dx}\left(3x^2+4\sqrt{x}\right) = 6x+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$, but I'm having a trouble proving this with a certain method, you see I was training on the basic method -I don't really know what they call it- to get back to the origins of calculus, which is $\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

I've done the following:
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac {3(x+h)^2+4\sqrt{x+h}-3x^2-4\sqrt{x}}{h}$$
which is so far correct, but I'm struggling to transform this to $6x+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$, I know the problem isn't hard but I wish that someone will be kind and tell me what the next step is.

Comment: Try doing this as two separate problems, one for $3x^2$, the other for $4\sqrt x$ (and factor out the constants).

Comment: I am not sure about how general this terminology is, but I believe that the "origins of calculus" method is referred to as *differentiation by first principles*. In any case, along with the hint above, for $\frac{3(x+h)^2 - 3x^2}{h}$, life is easy because the $h$ cancels out. For the other term $\frac{4(\sqrt{x+h} - \sqrt{x})}{h}$, multiply and divide by $\sqrt{x+h} + \sqrt{x}$ ("rationalization"), then $h$ can go to $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've done something similar but I ended up with $6x$ only, not $6x + \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer oh I guess I understand you, I'll try it thanks

Comment: Well, "obviously" the answer will be the sum of the answers of the two pieces :)

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry I guess I've done a small yet strange mistake but now I understand it, thanks for your help anyway

Comment: @Ryu Sure, have a go and see if what I've said works out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake. There was a $- 4\sqrt{x}$ not $+4\sqrt{x}$.

$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac {3(x+h)^2+4\sqrt{x+h}-3x^2-4\sqrt{x}}{h}& = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac {3x^2 + 6xh+3h^2+4\sqrt{x+h}-3x^2-4\sqrt{x}}{h}\\& = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac {6xh+3h^2+4\sqrt{x+h}-4\sqrt{x}}{h}\\&=   \lim_{h \to 0}\frac {6xh+3h^2}{h}+\frac{4\sqrt{x+h}-4\sqrt{x}}{h}\\& =   \lim_{h \to 0}{6x+3h}+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{4(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x+h}+ \sqrt{x})}{h\sqrt{x+h}+ \sqrt{x})}\\&= 6x+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{4(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x+h}+ \sqrt{x})}{h(\sqrt{x+h}+ \sqrt{x})}\\& =  6x+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{4}{(\sqrt{x+h}+ \sqrt{x})}\\& =   6x+\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I did notice my mistake and now I understand how the limit is evaluated, thanks again :)